# Invalidtokenexception from ActiveCollab API

Tags: activecollab

I have created token using issue-token Api and passed this token  as bearer token to call another api to get the task details.But I am getting Invalidtokenexception.

I have generated token using "issue-token-intent"(https://app.activecollab.com/ACTIVE COLLAB ID/api/v1/issue-token-intent) API with Intent,client_vendor and client name.

exception details

{
"type": "ActiveCollab\Authentication\Exception\InvalidTokenException",
"message": "Authorization token is not valid",
"code": 0
}

I need to  get the API to fetch all attachments in a task/project